# How do I get SqlCommand ExecuteNonQuery result?

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

In order to check if specific user is db_owner, i excute the following query:

```
"select is_rolemember('db_owner', '" & p_userName & "')"
```

using the `SqlCommand` `ExecuteNonQuery` method.

How do I get the query result?

Here is my code:

```
    Dim com As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, m_connection)               
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

sql is the query, and m_connection is the connectionString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx), not [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ExecuteScalar`

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in
>   the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are
>   ignored.

like Lucero said.

EX:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.region";
Int32 count = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Returning the `Int`.

Answer (score 2):

While everyone has given the answer I would like to point out that your sql is vulnerable to injection if p_userName can in anyway be influenced by a client.

Also note that is_rolemember can return Null ([See Microsoft Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677633%28v=sql.110%29.aspx))
Below is an implementation that is not vulnerable to Sql Injection (it uses parameterized sql).

```
Dim com As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("select is_rolemember('db_owner', @UserName)", m_connection)
com.Parameters. AddWithValue("@UserName", p_userName)
Dim result As Object = com.ExecuteScalar
If (result = DBNull.Value) Then
   Throw New Exception("database_principal or role is not valid, or you do not have permission to view the role membership.")
Else
    Return CType(result,Int32)
End If
```